# Get checkbox value in a variable in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vb.net, checkbox

I am trying to retrieve a checkbox value (If its checked or not) in AJAX in vb.net). But cannot seem to get the value. I am using the following method.

```
var myCheckBoxValue= $('#<%=myCheckBox.ClientID %>').val();
```

**"myCheckBox"** is the name of my checkbox
 Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's wrong.
To get if a checkbox is checked or not you should do like this:

```
 $('#<%=myCheckBox.ClientID %>').prop( "checked" )
```

Reference: [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: No problem! If it helped please mark my answer as "right answer" to help other people :)

Comment: Thanks :)  Works perfect